# MongoDB statefulset updating

Tags: mongodb, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am in the process of deploying a `mongodb` `ReplicaSet` on `GKE`.

My deployment works, however I would like to enable auth on Mongo.

I have connected to my pod

```
kubectl exec -it {pod_name} mongo admin
```

Created an Admin user and also a user for my database. I was then thinking I could update `mongo-statefulset.yaml` with the `--auth` flag and apply the updated `yaml`.

Something like

```
.....
spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongod-container
          image: mongo:3.6
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--bind_ip"
            - "0.0.0.0"
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
            - "--auth"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
.....
```

But running `kubectl apply -f mongo-statefulset.yaml` just produces

> service/mongo-svc unchanged
>
> statefulset.apps/mongo configured

Should I restart my pods for this to now take effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do **rolling update**:
The RollingUpdate update strategy will update all Pods in a StatefulSet, in reverse ordinal order, while respecting the StatefulSet guarantees.

Patch the web StatefulSet to apply the RollingUpdate update strategy.

```
$ kubectl patch statefulset your_statefulset_name -p '{"spec":{...}}}'
```

Don't to forget to add env label with credentials you have created on your pod like:

```
      env:
        - name: MONGODB_USERNAME
          value: admin
        - name: MONGODB_PASSWORD
          value: password
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
kubectl delete -f mongo-statefulset.yaml && kubectl apply -f mongo-statefulset.yaml
```